# Freebsd ports installing with parameters

Tags: freebsd

I'm trying to create a install script for some FreeBSD machines.

I want to install a few ports but change several configurations before installing, and without the dialog popup.

I've tried almost everything but no success.

I.E:
I'm trying to install nginx with HTTP_SSL module but i can't seem to pass the correct parameter to the make install clean command. I also want to use all other default settings, and only change this one.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Copying files like /var/db/ports/nginx/options accross several machines?

Comment: I'm looking for the command to do it automatically and not copy the same file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://wiki.freebsd.org/Ports/Options/OptionsNG

It describes different ways to preset the options of a port